# Relative URL in css var works wrong on iOS

Tags: ios, css-variables

Relative URL in css var on iOS gets related file where this var was **determined**, instead of where it **used**, so URL is wrong.

Example: if to determinate url var into `index.html`

```
:root {--theme-bg: url('../img/white_rose.jpg');}
```

and to use it in separately `style.css` - in all browsers URL will be relative to this `style.css` and full URL will be `http://domain/assets/img/white_rose.jpg`
[image]

but on iOS will be relative `index.html` so final URL will be `http://domain/img/white_rose.jpg`
[image]

Anyone had this? Is this possible to fix somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact issue, code here: https://github.com/warlockuk/safarivarurl

It's Safari.  It seems to process the fallback url relative to the HTML, not the CSS file that contained it.

If you take the fallback URL out of the var and just set it straight on the HTML everything is fine.